# Сколько в массиве частей?

Tags: python

Как узнать - из скольких частей состоит массив `a = [ [1,7], [5,3], [6,2], [2,5] ]`?
В данном случае 4 (то есть скобок [] четыре - не знаю как правильно назвать).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Называется длина

```
len(a)
```

*И не массив, а список.*

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае список `a` состоит из подсписков. Длину списка можно узнать, используя

```
len(a)
```